# How much do you heal with a Anstruth Harp's Cure Wounds

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Anstruth Harp is a magic item that allows you to cast a 5th level version of *cure wounds*

> You can use your action to play the instrument and cast one of its spells

Cure Wounds states (emphasis mine):

> When you cast this spell **using a spell slot** of 2nd level or higher, the healing increases by 1d8 for each slot level above 1st.

Since you are not casting with a higher level spell slot, does the status of the spell as 5th level serve no benefit to the healing?

Answer (score 6):

### Cure Wounds would heal 5d8+spell mod

> ### Casting a Spell at a Higher Level
>
> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting. For instance, if Umara casts magic missile using one of her 2nd-level slots, **that magic missile is 2nd level**.
>   (PHB 201)

Using the Magic Item bypasses the need to use a spell slot and enables you to cast it at a higher level. The next paragraph of the rulebook even states that some spells have more powerful effects when cast at a higher-level.

Answer (score 1):

Just as it says: Cure Wounds cast as a 5th level spell; it will cure 5d8 (+ the player's stat bonus) in hp.